# Redundant tag: [review]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Since this site is about reviewing codes, [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is complete, and I also made it an intrinsic tag for the site.