# Tag-request [overall-review]

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, tags

I don't quite understand how the process of tag-creation works.

In [JavaScript text editing webapp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35280/javascript-text-editing-webapp), I've added [overall-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overall-review) to the tags list and thought that I would be able to edit the wiki and such right away, but this is not the case.

1. Do I need a certain amount of rep to create tags?
2. Does tag creation fall to the moderators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not fall to the moderators.  According to the [tag creation privilege page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), 150 rep is required to create tags.  This takes effect immediately *unless* one doesn't have editing privileges (1000 rep), in which case the request still has to be approved.

Moreover, I have denied that tag creation suggestion.  It doesn't seem like a tag that we need.  Plus, we should help the asker stay at or below the five-tag limit by not giving him/her so many options.

I also don't entirely agree with "adding more tags for visibility."  On a question list page alone, this is irrelevant because it's the *title* that stands out.  As for favorited tags, it's safe to assume that users mostly follow language tags, which obviously are already used.  What matters is that the *correct* tags are used.

Comment: there are a lot of questions where the OP gives one tag, and the OP wants a General Review, I think this would be a good tag to add.  I remember seeing somewhere on StackOverflow that a Poster should always have at least 2-3 tags on their question for max attention.  I have been adding tags to questions where they fit, but I think this tag would benefit everyone, at the same time it may make people more lazy

Comment: sometimes, users will use the Android tag with out the Java Tag.  or they will tag with some obscure javascript tag that doesn't have very many followers and forget the javascript tag. that is what I am talking about when I say adding tags.  I also remove excess tags, like when someone tags with asp.net-mvc3 and asp.net-mvc4 and asp.net I remove the tag that doesn't make sense

Comment: @Malachi: Yes, I understand.  That's what I would consider correctness of using tags.  On the other hand, your Cold Fusion question reveals the use of an extra tag without the more common tag.  In any case, this answer is for addressing generalities and is not a direct criticism of the recent tagging.

Answer (score -2):

I just found this post as it closely relates to this question.

[Redundant tag: review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/redundant-tag-review)

and I think this question and answer says it clearly.

---

<strike>this was a comment but I think it might be deserving as an answer.</strike>

there are a lot of questions where the OP gives one tag, and the OP wants a General Review,

I think this would be a good tag to add.

I remember seeing somewhere on StackOverflow that a Poster should always have at least 2-3 tags on their question for max attention.

I have been adding tags to questions where they fit, but I think this tag would benefit everyone, at the same time it may make people more lazy

Comment: But think about _why_ the guideline of 2 to 3 tags exists. I doubt anyone will subscribe to an overall-review tag, so it would just be noise.